# Could not create new component in angular 8

Tags: angular

I couldn't create new application in angular 8, when I run these comment shows error(this is the first time).
ng new my-dream-app
I had attached the screenshot of these error please check it.
Can you please help me to resolve these issue .

[Error screnshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HPYP.png)

Comment: Did you try to run `npm install`?

Comment: Try to clean your npm cache `npm cache clean --force` then retry to `ng new ...`

Comment: @Alexix ,when running these clean comment shows these error   -   npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues 
and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure 
everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead. On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue 
with the installer, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.